# foreach, explode and keeping data in same array

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I am trying to convert my example_data to be in the same array:

```
$example_data = "FirstName=Test&LastName=TestLastName&Address=ExampleSt";
$explode1 = explode('&', $example_data);

$data_array = array();
foreach ($explode1 as $values)
{
    $explode2 = explode("=", $values);

    $field_name = $explode2[0];
    $field_value =  $explode2[1];

    $data_array[] = array(
        $field_name    =>    $field_value
        );
}                

echo json_encode($data_array);
```

The current output - separated arrays:

> [{"FirstName":"Test"},{"LastName":"TestLastName"},{"Address":"ExampleSt"}]

The intended output I am looking for:

> {"FirstName":Test,"LastName":TestLastName,"Address":ExampleSt}

Comment: `data_array[$field_name] = $field_value;`

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration you add an array at the end of `$data_array`. Instead, you could just directly use `$field_name` as a key and `$field_value` as a value:

```php
foreach ($explode1 as $values)
{
    $explode2 = explode("=", $values);

    $field_name = $explode2[0];
    $field_value =  $explode2[1];

    $data_array[$field_name] = $field_value; # Here!
}
```

**EDIT:**

As a side note, PHP has a built-in function called [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) that can do all this heavy lifting for you:

```php
$example_data = "FirstName=Test&LastName=TestLastName&Address=ExampleSt";
$data_array = array();
parse_str($example_data, $data_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for that:

```
parse_str($example_data, $data_array);
echo json_encode($data_array);
```